# How to re-enable Internet Explorer after disabling it and downgrading (11->9)

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

I need to test a site on IE9 for a client. For technical reasons, I'm forced to work on a Windows 7 virtual machine, which runs IE11. So I found [this tutorial](http://techshangrila.blogspot.ch/2014/01/how-to-downgrade-from-ie-11-to-lower.html) which basically says you can do that by first disabling IE as part of the Windows features, and then find IE11 in the "installed updates" listing (in Windows Update) and uninstall it from here. So to get to IE9, I have to do that twice.

Actually I didn't follow exactly the procedure. Here's what I did:

1. I went first to the installed updates part, found IE11, uninstalled it and restarted Windows. When I launched IE again, I confirmed (via the "About" dialog box) that it had been downgraded to IE10. So at that point I had **not** disabled IE in the "Turn Windows features on or off" window.
2. Then I thought that maybe I was missing something important by not disabling IE before uninstalling the relevant update, so I went to the "Turn Windows features on or off" window and disabled Internet Explorer here.
3. Then I went back to the installed updates and uninstalled the update "Internet Explorer 10". Then rebooted the machine.

And that's where I am now: the problem is that IE seems to have been completely uninstalled, not just downgraded, and is **not even listed anymore** in the "Turn Windows features on or off" window. So I have no way (that I know of) to re-enable it.

I tried to download IE9 through various sites (using Firefox to download Internet Explorer, that's not something you do everyday!), but the installation fails, saying there is already a more recent version installed.

If I go to the "installed updates" page, I can see "Internet Explorer 9" listed here. So I could uninstall it, but at this point I'm not sure it's very wise...

So it seems IE is still here, but non-functional and non-"enablable"...

Any idea how to fix this mess?

Comment: You are aware that Microsoft provides a virtual machine of every possible version of IE and Windows for exactly this purpose.  Might be easier to use one of those virtual machines then change your current solution.  They also provide them in the major 3 virtual machine formats for VirtualBox, VMware, and Hyper-V.  It also possible that depending on your configuration, you won't be able to roll back to IE9, because the information required to uninstall IE10 isn't present within the SxS store.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was not aware of that solution. Do you happen to have a link for it? (Or is it this? https://www.modern.ie/ )

Comment: You linked to it.  I only suggest it because you could spend hours trying to modify your current virtual machine instead the 20 minutes it would take to download and launch a virtual machine designed for exactly this purpose :-)